# How to pick a Balun and transformer for this power line measurement circuit

Tags: communication, mains

I was reading this paper [here](http://www.isplc.org/docsearch/Proceedings/2003/pdf/A6-3.pdf) about measuring power line impedance using a network analyzer.  It has a little circuit that they used but of course they're not nice enough to include a BOM :)

How would I go about choosing a Balun and transformer like the one they used here?[image]